# Accessing tag as an environment variable inside a Docker container

Tags: git, docker

I'd like to be able to access the tag/revision used to build a docker container from within that container. Is there a simple way to surface the tag/revision during the build as an environmental variable?

For example, I would like an API running inside a container to know its current revision. Without docker I would normally use git to write the revision to the a file that the API can access, but this doesn't seem to be the "Docker way".

Answer (score 8):

This is now possible with docker build arguments.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

`docker build --build-arg TAG=v0.0.1 .`

**PS**: For a multistage build, you need to pass it via all build stages.

Comment: Interesting but there is no guarantee that TAG will be same as the image tag. In fact the tag can be changed easily after build using `docker tag`. What is needed is really a run-time environment variable that docker would set as part of the `docker run` command, that's when the tag used for the container is known.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an API, but you can always pass the tag with the `-e` of the run command. A short example `$ docker run -it -e mytag=abc123 ubuntu:latest env | grep mytag
mytag=abc123`
 and so inside your container mytag will contain the tag of the container.

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for, but still doesn't enforce that whatever was passed to -t during the build process is surfaced inside the container when ran. I want my automated build to be able to inject this value into the container at build time.

Comment: You can also have in your Dockerfile a line `ENV mytag xxx`, then inside your running container you will have an environment variable coming from your build time

Comment: Yup, thought of that as well, but that would require my build to edit my Dockerfile. Not the end of the world, but I'm surprised there isn't a simple way to access information about the container from within the container.

Answer (score 0):

seems the directly answer is **NO**
(the ARG/ENV just workaroud)

And I trying to understand why, by compare it to ARG/ENV.

- ARG/ENV store infomation in storage layer
- `ARG` is build-time const
  //runtime can't access in container, but user can inspect image see it
- `ENV` is build-time & runtime const
- image `tag` is different
- has nothing on storage layer

  - can't direct access in container
- some kind of meta data for image (on host)

  - can be change at build-time or run-time (one image, multi tag, or no tag)
    //not in the same dimension with container
    //but the tag name passed to `docker build` should special (like ARG/ENV)?

at last, I guess it's by design, they want

- keep tag only in host context (and mark image at anytime)
- only for image select (not affect container in other way)

---

BTW, try to understand env and arg (maybe off-topic)
(maybe not entirely accurate)

|  | build-time | build-time | runtime | runtime | image | container |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | set | get | set | get | inspect | inspect |
| ENV | dockerfile | env | cmdline | env | in config | in config |
| ARG | dockerfile cmdline | env | NA | NA | in layer | NA |
| tag | cmdline | NA | cmdline | NA | in meta | in config |