# Read docker tag from container

Tags: docker

Is it possible to get the current image tag inside a running container? Currently I am passing an environment variable with the same name as the tag, but it would be nice if I could somehow read it from a docker supplied environment variable.

```
<name>/<image>:<tag>
```

I am doing a `sed` in a config based on the `<tag>`.

Comment: Maybe related: [Accessing tag as an environment variable inside a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28128649/accessing-tag-as-an-environment-variable-inside-a-docker-container)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind adding curl and jq to the container and also mounting the docker socket , you can retrieve the image by running the following script inside the container:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONTAINER_ID=$(head -1 /proc/self/cgroup | rev | cut -d/ -f 1 | rev)
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/v1.40/containers/{$CONTAINER_ID}/json | jq .Config.Image
```

The first line gets the container id from /proc/self/cgroup and the second uses docker api to inspect the container.

Comment: Could it be there's something wrong with the URL you're passing to curl? I get an error `curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server`. I've changed it to `http://docker:2375/v1.40...` as it's something I see recurring on the internet, but to the same effect.

Comment: Mounting Docker socket is of high-security risk. You give VM root access to this particular container.

Comment: @mierzwid is your comment regarding `http://docker:2375/v1.40...` in the first comment, or `http:/v1.40/containers...` in the answer? Just so I can be sure which one _shouldn't_ be used because it "give[s] VM root access to this particular container"

Comment: My comment is regarding starting the Docker container in privilege mode, when it has access to the /var/run/docker.sock. Access to docker.sock == root access to the machine.